# Use hasura with Google Cloud Run and Google Cloud SQL

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run, hasura

The docs describe that hasura needs the postgres connection string with the  `HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL` env var.

Example:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 \
  -e HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL=postgres://username:password@hostname:port/dbname \
  hasura/graphql-engine:latest
```

It looks like that my problem is that the server instance connection name for google cloud sql looks like `PROJECT_ID:REGION:INSTANCE_ID` is not TCP

From the cloud run docs (https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run) I got this example:

`postgres://<db_user>:<db_pass>@/<db_name>?unix_sock=/cloudsql/<cloud_sql_instance_name>/.s.PGSQL.5432` but it does not seem to work. Ideas?

I'm currently adding the `cloud_sql_proxy` as a workaround to the container so that I can connect to TCP 127.0.0.1:5432, but I'm looking for a direct connection to google-cloud-sql.

// EDIT Thanks for the comments, beta8 did mostly the trick, but I also missed the `set-cloudsql-instances` parameter: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/run/deploy#--set-cloudsql-instances

My full cloud-run command:

```
gcloud beta run deploy \
    --image gcr.io/<PROJECT_ID>/graphql-server:latest \
    --region <CLOUD_RUN_REGION> \
    --platform managed \
    --set-env-vars HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL="postgres://<DB_USER>:<DB_PASS>@/<DB_NAME>?host=/cloudsql/<PROJECT_ID>:<CLOUD_SQL_REGION>:<INSTANCE_ID>" \
    --timeout 900 \
    --set-cloudsql-instances <PROJECT_ID>:<CLOUD_SQL_REGION>:<INSTANCE_ID>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [v1.0.0-beta.8](https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/releases/tag/v1.0.0-beta.8), which  has better support for Postgres connection string parameters, I've managed to make the unix connection to work, from Cloud Run to Cloud SQL, without embedding the proxy into the container.

The connection should look something like this:

```
postgres://<user>:<password>@/<database>?host=/cloudsql/<instance_name>
```

Notice that the client will add the suffix `/.s.PGSQL.5432` for you.

Make sure you added also the Cloud SQL client permission.

Comment: I'm receiving this error:

```{code: postgres-error, error: connection error, internal: could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/cloudsql/<instance_name>/.s.PGSQL.5432"? , path: $}``` - the instance name should be correct. Ideas? I added the cloud sql permissions.

Comment: I'll create a repo to reproduce and we can discuss from there. Will update here as soon as I get it done tomorrow.

Comment: Looking for this kind of solution for weeks! Thanks :)

Comment: More details how to use this solution are in this repo: https://github.com/n3n/hasura-cloud-run

Answer (score 3):

If the Hasura database requires that exact connection string format, you can use it. However, you cannot use Cloud Run's Cloud SQL support. You will need to whitelist the entire Internet so that your Cloud Run instance can connect. Cloud Run does not publish a CIDR block of addresses. This method is not recommended.

The Unix Socket method is for Cloud SQL Proxy that Cloud Run supports. This is the connection method used internally to your container when Cloud Run is managing the connection to Cloud SQL. Note, for this method IP based hostnames are not supported in your client to connect to Cloud Run's Cloud SQL Proxy.

You can embed the Cloud SQL Proxy directly in your container. Then you can use 127.0.0.1 as the hostname part for the connection string. This will require that you create a shell script as your Cloud Run entrypoint to launch both the proxy and your application. Based on your scenario, I recommend this method.

The Cloud SQL Proxy is written in Go and the source code is published.

If you choose to embed the proxy, don't forget to add the Cloud SQL Client role to the Cloud Run service account.

Comment: Currently no Cloud SQL Proxy is needed in newest versions.